# Relaciones entre collections mongo

Tags: mongodb

Estoy iniciando en `Mongodb`, y como saben este no tiene `relaciones`, no hay `joins` `tablas` etc.

intento pasar un diagrama relacional a `NOSQL`. Tengo las siguientes tablas.

**users**

```
id

name
```

**messages**

```
idUserFrom

idUserTo

messages
```

como ven la tabla `messages` tiene como foraneas el id de `users`, como puedo crear aunque en mongo no hay `pks` y `fks` como puedo realizar este paso.

Hasta ahorita realice la creacion de la base de datos y una `collection` con insercion de la tabla `users`.

```
> use mongodb
switched to db mongodb
> db
mongodb
> db.users.insert({id:"1",name:"Jorge"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> show collections
users
> db.users.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c9bbc275a56aa679bb06155"),
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Jorge"
}
```

Como le puedo hacer para que quede de la siguiente manera siendo esta la `collections` de `messages`:
Esta taba contiene el id de algun usuario, que puede ser el `idFrom` o `idTo`

```
db.messages.find().pretty();



  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c9bbc275a56aa679bb06155"),
            "idFrom" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "idTo"   : "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "message" : "Hola"
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En MongoDB sí existen las relaciones entre colecciones. Lo que sucede es que Mongo es una base de datos **noSQL**. Esto significa que no usa el lenguaje estructurado de consultas (o SQL en inglés). Por lo tanto, no hay una sentencia como `SELECT * FROM table`, ya que la misma es propia de dicho lenguaje.

Por otro lado, se tiende a confundir el término "base de datos **no relacional**" con la ausencia de relaciones. La verdad es que Mongo permite implementar relaciones, pero a través de algo que se conoce como *referencias*. Incluso se habla tranquilamente de cardinalidad de las relaciones, con las mismas características que conocemos en una base de datos "relacional". La particularidad de Mongo (así como de muchas otras BD *noSQL*) es que no se ajusta o no se apega fielmente al modelo E-R (Entidad - Relación), de allí su descripción como una BD **no relacional**.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea crear una relación entre dos colecciones de Mongo. Una colección, llamada *users*, tendrá una relación con otra colección llamada *messages*. Se requiere que cada documento tipo `message` posea una referencia en dos de sus campos a un documento tipo `user`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr lo que nos proponemos debemos crear una referencia a `user` en cada campo del documento tipo `message` donde deseamos crear la relación. Mongo nos ofrece dos tipo de [Referencias](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)

***Las Referencias Manuales***

Son las que se usan colocando el valor de `_id` de un documento en el campo de otro documento. Luego, si se desea obtener el documento asociado al `_id` se debe realizar una segunda consulta a la base de datos usando la información de dicho valor.

Supongamos que creamos la colección `users` de la siguiente manera:

```
> db.users.insert([{"name": "Mauricio", "email": "mauricio@email.com"},{"name": "Patricio", "email": "patricio@email.com"}])
```

Si deseamos ver los objetos de la colección `users` que acabamos de crear usaremos el método `find()`:

```
> db.users.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "name" : "Mauricio", "email" : "mauricio@email.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "name" : "Patricio", "email" : "patricio@email.com" }
```

Podemos apreciar que Mongo ha asignado los valores `_id` como tipo `ObjectId`. Esto lo hace automáticamente a menos que nosotros le pasemos un valor para el campo `_id` explicítamente.

Ahora crearemos la colección `messages` he introduciremos la referencia manualmente. Esto lo logramos de la siguiente manera:

```
> var idMauricio = ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06")
> var idPatricio = ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07")
> db.messages.insert([{"idFrom": idMauricio, "idTo": idPatricio, "message": "¿Como estas?"},{"idFrom": idPatricio, "idTo": idMauricio, "message": "Muy bien, gracias"}])
```

(hemos usado los valores `_id` correspondientes)

Si deseamos ver los documentos de la colección `messages` hacemos nuevamente uso del método `find()`:

```
> db.messages.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd08"), "idFrom" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "idTo" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "message" : "¿Como estas?" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd09"), "idFrom" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "idTo" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "message" : "Muy bien, gracias" }
```

Ahora ya tenemos relacionados manualmente documentos de la colección `messages` con documentos de la colección `users`.

Muchas veces este tipo de relaciones manuales serán suficientes para nuestra aplicación. Sin embargo, para saber el nombre o el correo del usuario que envió el mensaje o el usuario que recibió el mensaje, debemos hacer una segunda consulta a la base de datos:

```
> var cursor = db.messages.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd08")},{"_id":0, "idFrom": 1})
> var message = cursor.hasNext() ? cursor.next() : null
> if (message) {
... var id = message.idFrom
... }
> db.users.find({"_id": id})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "name" : "Mauricio", "email" : "mauricio@email.com" }
```

En la consulta anterior he usado una `query` (`{"_id" : ObjectId("5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd08")}`) en el método `find()`, y además le he pasado como parámetro un `projection` (`{"_id":0, "idFrom": 1}`).

Si quisiéramos hacer una consulta similar en SQL, se podría escribir así:

```
SELECT idFrom FROM messages WHERE id = "5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd08"
```

Puedes consultar más información sobre el método `find()` en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

**Las referencias DBRef**

***DBRefs*** es una convención usada para representar un documento, en vez de un tipo de referencia específica (manual) como la que acabamos de ver. Las referencias de este tipo incluyen el nombre de la colección a la que pertenece el documento, el valor del campo `_id` del documento y puede incluir el nombre de la base de datos a la que pertenece la colección.

Un docuemento `DBRef` tiene el siguiente formato: (es importante respetar el orden de los campos)

```
{"$ref": <value>, "$id": <value>, "$db": <value>}
```

Para usar una referencia tipo `DBRef` en nuestro caso lo podemos hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
> db.messages2.insert([{"idFrom": {"$ref": "users", "$id": ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07")}, "idTo": {"$ref": "users", "$id": ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06")}, "message": "Gracias por responder"},{"idFrom": {"$ref": "users", "$id": ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06")}, "idTo": {"$ref": "users", "$id": ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07")}, "message": "Un gusto ayudarte"}])
```

Si realizamos una consulta a nuestra colección `messages2` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
> db.messages2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cd7e3b6e8c62ece6b9981"), "idFrom" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07")), "idTo" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06")), "message" : "Gracias por responder" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cd7e3b6e8c62ece6b9982"), "idFrom" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06")), "idTo" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07")), "message" : "Un gusto ayudarte" }
```

De esta forma tenemos creada la relación entre la colección `messages2` y la colección `users` usando `DBRefs`.

Nuevamente, para conocer el nombre o correo de usuario que envía o recibe se debe realizar una segunda consulta a la base de datos

**JOIN**

Ahora, ya que la pregunta plantea si se pueden hacer JOINs en Mongo, la respuesta es: SI, usaando un método llamado `aggregate()`, que como su traducción supone, agrega algo a nuestra consulta. En este caso podemos agregar los documentos asociados con el `_id` en los campos `idFrom` e `idTo` de la colección `messages`. Este tipo de `aggregation` se conoce como [`$lookup aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). De esta forma tenemos una manera de traer los datos en una sola consulta.

Un ejemplo sencillo de esto lo podemos ver en la siguiente consulta:

```
> db.messages.aggregate([ {$lookup: {from: "users", localField: "idFrom", foreignField: "_id", as: "sender" }}, {$lookup: {from: "users", localField: "idTo", foreignField: "_id", as: "receiver" }}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd08"), "idFrom" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "idTo" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "message" : "¿Como estas?", "sender" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "name" : "Mauricio", "email" : "mauricio@email.com" } ], "receiver" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "name" : "Patricio", "email" : "patricio@email.com" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cce340aee604c4ab6cd09"), "idFrom" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "idTo" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "message" : "Muy bien, gracias", "sender" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd07"), "name" : "Patricio", "email" : "patricio@email.com" } ], "receiver" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c9ccc140aee604c4ab6cd06"), "name" : "Mauricio", "email" : "mauricio@email.com" } ] }
```

Básicamente le estamos diciendo a Mongo que ***busque*** (*lookup*) los documentos en la colección `users` cuyo `_id` coincida con el campo `idFrom` e `idTo` y los ***agregue*** al documento devuelto en un campo `sender` y un campo `receiver`.

Esto traducido a SQL es un JOIN sencillo, o tal vez una consulta del tipo:

```
SELECT *, sender, receiver 
FROM messages 
WHERE sender IN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = messages.idFrom)
AND receiver IN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = messages.idTo)
```

Como puedes ver, casi todo lo que se hace con SQL se puede hacer en Mongo.

Espero que sea la respuesta que estabas buscando.