# MongoDB: insertar data de una coleccion en otra

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, collection

Antes que nada disculpen si no son los terminos correctos los que uso, realmente el backend no es lo mio. Explico mi problema. Tengo dos colecciones, una es para mostrar una lista de peliculas en el front-end y se ve asi.
Estoy haciendo como practica una copia de Netflix.
Si alguien me pudiera guiar almenos que es lo que tendria que buscar en la web seria genial, desde ya muchas gracias!

```
{
    "nombre":"Series de Comedia",
    "genero":"Comedia",
    "tipo":"serie",
    "contenido":["61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a",
    "61a837497e67667fb2455c7a"]
}
```

En la parte de "contenido" yo necesito que tome dinamicamente de la otra coleccion peliculas o seriasy tambien las filtre segun el genero y uno de los item de la otra lista se ve asi, pero buenos son varios, dejo uno de ejemplo:

```
{
        "esPelicula": true,
        "destacada": false,
        "_id": "61bd5199e3951babf9e6fbd0",
        "nombre": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        "director": "Frank Darabont",
        "protagonistas": "Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler",
        "duracion": "142 minutos",
        "trailer": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hB3S9bIaco",
        "imagen": "https://mediad.publicbroadcasting.net/p/wcbe/files/styles/x_large/public/202004/shaw_2.jpg",
        "fecha_de_Estreno": 1994,
        "sinopsis": "En 1947, Andy Dufresne (Tim Robbins), un joven banquero, es condenado a cadena perpetua por asesinar a su esposa y su amante. A pesar de declararse inocente, es encarcelado en Shawshank, el penitenciario más duro del estado de Maine.",
        "genero": "Drama",
        "destacado": false,
        "vista": false,
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: Sugiero dar una revisión a [consultas de agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/); luego intentar usar el stage [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) para unir las colecciones (por genero x ejemplo)y a partir de ahi filtrar. Puedes compartir lo que hayas intentado editando la pregunta y a partir de ahí, la comunidad te puede apoyar. Saludos

Comment: [Pregunta relacionada S.O. en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249344/relaciones-entre-collections-mongo/249626#249626)

Comment: Gracias @g.4, ahora vere lo que me recomendaste

Comment: seguro, en realidad no es obligatorio que compartas lo que has intentado, hay colegas que contestan las preguntas aunque el OP(Original Poster, o sea tú) no muestre ningún [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), y puede que alguien te ayude a contestar la pregunta así como esta; pero siempre es bueno demostrar un esfuerzo y la pregunta es mejor recibida por los colegas más activos dentro de la comunidad. Saludos